Can Goodstein's theorem be proven in $\mathrm{PA + Con(PA)}$?
We define the Goodstein sequence $G_k(n)$ by first expressing $k$ in hereditary-base-$2$ notation (see the Wikipedia article for an explanation of this) and setting $G_k(2) = k$. Then to get $G_k(n + 1)$, we take the expression of $G_k(n)$ in hereditary-base-$n$ notation, replace the occurrences of $n$ with $(n + 1)$, subtract $1$, and reexpress the result in hereditary-base-$(n + 1)$ notation.
Goodstein's theorem then says that $G_k(n)$ always reaches $0$ for a sufficiently large $n$, no matter the $k$.
The Kirby-Paris theorem then says that Goodstein's theorem is independent of Peano Arithmetic ($\mathrm{PA}$), and can be proven by showing that $\mathrm{PA}$ proves $\mathrm{Goodstein} \implies \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$. Goodstein's theorem itself can be proven easily using countable ordinals from a theory like $\mathrm{ZFC}$, in fact only requiring ordinals up to $\varepsilon_0$.
Now, this is easy to find materials for (for example the original paper by Paris and Kirby), but I often see the stronger claim that Goodstein's theorem is equivalent to $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$. See for example this Stack Exchange question, this MathOverflow question or this discussion. However, I haven't found any proof of this. Is it actually true?
If I understand the matter correctly, this question could also be asked by considering Gentzen's proof of the consistency of $\mathrm{PA}$ given $\mathrm{PRA}$ and transfinite induction up to $\varepsilon_0$. But again, I only see references for the direction towards $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$, not from it.

No https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155329/what-is-the-proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-pa-conpa-pa-conpa-conpa-etc

@spaceisdarkgreen Well, that was unexpected! If you turn your comment into an answer (quoting the relevant parts for the benefit of future Googlers), I can accept it.

No, as shown by Henry Towsner here, adding true $\Pi_1$ statements to $\sf PA$ does not add any more provably total recursive functions. Goodstein's theorem is a statement that a certain recursive function (namely the one mapping $k$ to the least $n$ such that $G_k(n)=0$) is total. This function grows faster than any $\sf PA$-provably total recursive function, so Goodstein's theorem can't be proved by adding true $\Pi_1$ statements to $\sf PA.$ In fact, this immediately implies stronger independence: Goodstein's theorem is not provable in $\sf PA+Con(PA + Con(PA))$, $\sf PA + Con(PA + Con(PA + Con(PA))),$ etc.
Just to make sure we preserve the amount of potentially misinformative hearsay about this kind of thing in the world, let me add that I believe I learned at some point that Goodstein's theorem is equivalent (over $\sf PA$) to the consistency of "$\sf PA$ + all true $\Pi_1$ sentences" (and glancing at the Kirby-Paris paper without really thinking about it, this looks to be related to the results of Ketonen and Solovay used therein).

Thanks, it would do no good for the world to run out of mysteries ;)
